# searching from list search value may contains null value

Tags: c#

I have to search from `collection<List>`, during searching, list may or may not contains null value. But if null value is present it will search from other searching values.

My code is

```
List =
        ListAssetDetail.Where(
            e =>SelectedAsset.Equals(e.AssetName) && SlectedBroad.Equals(e.BroadcasterName) && SelectedAssetfor.Equals(e.AssetFrom) &&
           SelectedGenre.Equals(e.GenreName) && SelectedBoque.Equals(e.Subcategory) && SelectedContentType.Equals(e.AssetFor)).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to put more effort in explaining your problems. By this line "list may or may not contains null value" you mean "ListAssetDetail" might contain null values, right? "other searching values" means? Should your query skip that object in the collection if it is null? Please try to explain your problem a little more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant it to be a filter, you could probably use it like this:

```
        List = ListAssetDetail.Where( e => 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedAsset) || SelectedAsset.Equals(e.AssetName)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SlectedBroad) || SlectedBroad.Equals(e.BroadcasterName)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedAssetfor) || SelectedAssetfor.Equals(e.AssetFrom)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedGenre) || SelectedGenre.Equals(e.GenreName)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedBoque) || SelectedBoque.Equals(e.Subcategory)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedContentType) || SelectedContentType.Equals(e.AssetFor)));
```

So when a value is NULL, it will be skipped on the Equals. So each field should be match unless it's null or empty.

Comment: Isn't it a bit difficult to say that "SelectedAsset", etc are strings? They could be any structure or even objects in which case he/she is trying to check reference of.

Comment: I assume that properties like AssetName, GenreName are strings, why compare structure or even objects to Names. As you precisely noticed the question was concise written and based on that I made some assumptions.

Comment: It will be nice if you mention in your answer what you assumed. Thanks. :)